# How to pipe an log file CSV in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I would like to use PowerShell to parse a log, and output to a CSV file.

What is the basic way to accomplish this?

Comment: The `do something` in 4c74356b41's answer depends on the format of your log file. Eventually you can use `import-csv your.log` optionally with  -header ColA ...

Comment: Yeah, I was concerned that formatting for each log file would have affect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each log format involves it own logic when doing pattern matching, but I would propose to you something like:

(test.log is something like:
date - context - type - msg)

```
$file = get-content test.log
$pattern = '^(.*) - (.*) - (.*) - (.*)$'
$findings = $file | select-string -pattern $pattern
$lines = foreach($f in $findings) {
    if ($f -match $pattern) { 
      $line = @{
           'date' = $matches[1]
           'context' = $matches[2]
           'level' = $matches[3]
           'message' = $matches[4]
      }
      new-object -typename psobject -property $line
    }
}
$lines | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter ';' -path 'test.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content | do something | Export-CSV`